Trouble installing magento on Mac OS, issue with MySQL
I am getting this error when trying to setup Magento from the terminal on Mac OS localhost.
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
In InstallCommand.php line 282:
Parameter validation failed
I am able to login to MySQL in the command line and have verified that I have correct privileges for database and user. What could I be doing wrong?

Yeah, I remember hearing about some issues on macOS where there's a mix-up between 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' in Magento's env.php config file. That little difference can sometimes cause trouble, so it’s worth checking if that’s the case.
